# Writing Javadoc for return-type 'Optional<T>'

Tags: java, return, javadoc, option-type, return-type

I'm currently writing a Java-API for SOAP-webservices used at my workplace.
The webservice-classes are generated with *Axis2* and they can return `null`. As I don't want to deal with `null`-references on my business logic level, I'm using `Optional<>` as return-type.
For example:

```java
/**
 * Reads account-data to given accountId. 
 * 
 * @param accountId
 *          the primary key of table 'account'
 * @return  the account wrapped as an Optional<>, if an account with primary key 'accountId' exists; Optional.empty(), else
 */
public Optional<Account> readAccount(long accountId) throws RemoteException, ServiceFaultException {
        // prepare SOAP-Request
        ReadAccount request = new ReadAccount();
        request.setAccountId(accountId);

        // execute SOAP-Request
        ReadAccountResponse response = accountService.readAccount(request);

        // process Response
        Optional<Account> account = Optional.ofNullable(response.getAccount());

        return account;
    }
```

The above method executes a webservice-operation to search for some account-record in a database. If there is no account to be found with matching argument `accountId`, the method call `response.getAccount()` can return `null`.

Is there a more concise way of writing the Javadoc for `@return`?
Especially for the phrase "wrapped as an Optional<>"?

(I know that the answers might be opinion based, but I haven't found any recommendations for this on stackoverflow or by googling.)

Comment: Considering you are using the Optional the way it is generally used, just say you are returning an Optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simplying your return statement javadoc to the following:

```java
/**
 * Reads account-data to given accountId. 
 * 
 * @param accountId
 *          the primary key of table 'account'
 * @return the account wrapped in an {@link Optional}
 */
public Optional<Account> readAccount(long accountId) throws RemoteException, ServiceFaultException {
  // function here
}
```

the reason for this is because `Optional.empty()` is an expected and unchanging part of the `Optional` API; every developer who knows what an `Optional` is will know to expect an empty Optional if the account is missing; and will understand he needs to access the actual information inside the `Optional` if the account is present.

We provide a `@link` here to allow developers who haven't heard of `Optional`s to look up its respective javadoc and understand how it works; this is itself not mandatory, but can be helpful if there are a lot of less experienced developers working on your project.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. That seems like a short and accurate way of doing it.
I'll add this to my "best practice" repertoire  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not say it how the jdk does? For example `Stream::reduce`:

> @return an {@link Optional} describing the result of the reduction

In your case it would be:

> an Optional describing the account.

Comment: Thank you for the example.
I skimmed through the JDK API looking for an "official" example, but I couldn't find a method returning `Optional`.

Comment: @William there are methods returning `Optional` in the Optional documentation page itself: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html